# Same product enabled in a view and disabled in other not appear in 2 front

Tags: product, store-view

I have a magento store with 2 view :

- EN
- FR

When i disable a product in the 1 of the 2 views, my product disappear of the 2 front's view.

Is there a solution to keep visible this product in 1 view ?

Answer (score 1):

In the product you can choose the store view. 
Then you choose your store view where you want to disable it.

Choose for your example "FR" as store view and then set it to disabled there and save that. 
Then go to store view "EN" and see if its still enabled as it should be.

You can also instead of setting the status disabled, just change the visibility then.

[image: Product]

Answer (score 0):

Check the scope of your status field. If it's `global` or `website` then what ever you change on a store view level will be change don the other store views.
You can overcome this 2 ways.

1. The risky way, change the scope for the `status` field to `store view`. (Catalog->Attributes->Manage attributes).
2. The save (but ugly way). Use the attribute `visibility`. set the value to `not visible individually` on the store view you want. That attribute should already have the scope `store view`.

Comment: I'm sorry but you suggested in your first "risky way" to change the scope for the "status" field to "store view" but it's not possible. Only "website" and "global" scope are available...

Comment: You can di it from thr db. Or via upgrade script.

Comment: I do not think bypassing magento scope rules with db raw manipulation is a good advice.

Comment: It is not. But most probably it gets the job done. Anyway this is 2 years old. A lot changd since then.